# Inserting Array into Mongo using Mongoose not working

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to create a Mongo document but inserting into the array of the orderProducts element of the document is not working.

This is the method to create order and insert into Mongo:

```
exports.createOrder = function(req, res) {

    var delivery = JSON.parse(req.body.delivery);
    var payment = JSON.parse(req.body.payment);
    var orderProducts = JSON.parse(req.body.orderItems);

    console.log('delivery', delivery)
    console.log('payment', payment)
    console.log('orderProducts', orderProducts);

    var newOrder = new Order({delivery, payment, orderProducts});
   // newOrder.orderProducts.push(orderProducts);

    console.log('new order', newOrder)

    res.json({'a':'b'})
}
```

Upon parsing the data with this segment of code:

```
var delivery = JSON.parse(req.body.delivery);
var payment = JSON.parse(req.body.payment);
var orderProducts = JSON.parse(req.body.orderItems);
```

I get the expected results:

```
delivery:
 { firstName: 'fasdfasdf',
   lastName: 'dfasdas',
   email: 'asdfdfs@a',
   phone: 'addafdafd',
   shippingAddress: 'fasdfasdf',
   cityState: 'Brighton, MA',
   deliveryDate: 2018-04-06T00:00:00.000Z }

 payment:
  { paymentType: 'PayPal',
    cardNumber: 'fdasasdfdfaf',
    creditCardMonth: '11 - November',
    creditCardYear: '2028',
    cws: 'afd' },

orderProducts [ { productId: '596161e1734d1d25634366ce', quantity: 1 },
  { productId: '596269eb734d1d256343976a', quantity: 1 },
  { productId: '5962a556734d1d256343a210', quantity: 1 } ]
```

But when I create the Mongo document using this segment of code:

```
var newOrder = new Order({delivery, payment, orderProducts});
```

The delivery and payment elements of newOrder are correct as shown above but for orderProducts, the data is missing. I only get the following:

```
orderProducts:
 [ { _id: 5ae5cb11dba7821f1840475f },
   { _id: 5ae5cb11dba7821f1840475e },
   { _id: 5ae5cb11dba7821f1840475d } ]
```

This is the Mongoose model for order:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var DeliverySchema = new Schema({
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    email: String,
    phone: String,
    shippingAddress: String,
    cityState: String,
    zip: String,
    deliveryDate: Date,
    deliveryInstruction: String,
    useAsBillinAddress: Boolean
}, {_id: false});
mongoose.model('Delivery', DeliverySchema);

var PaymentSchema = new Schema({
    cardNumber: String,
    creditCardYear: String,
    creditCardMonth: String,
    cws: String,
    paymentType: String
}, {_id: false})
mongoose.model('Payment', PaymentSchema);

var OrderProductSchema = new Schema({
    id: String,
    qty: Number
}, {_id: false});
mongoose.model('OrderProduct', OrderProductSchema);

var OrderSchema = new Schema({
    delivery: DeliverySchema,
    payment: PaymentSchema,
    orderProducts: [{OrderProductSchema}],
    timestamp: {type: Date, default: Date.now}    
});

var Order = mongoose.model("Order", OrderSchema, "order");
module.exports = Order;
```

How do I insert an array into a document?

Comment: `orderProducts: [{OrderProductSchema}],` is Wrong. `orderProducts: [OrderProductSchema],` **without** the "braces" `{}`

Comment: That doesn't seem to solve it.